# Alternate object instead of using an enum for index values

Tags: c#, enums

My below code works fine, however, I would like to try and improve its portability. The `priceLevels` index numbers are subject to change, so instead of me having to update the program, I would like to have a settings option to set those index numbers.

I also want to be able to control the `ToString()` method for the `PriceLevel` class.

The `PriceLevel` class will be a part of my `Customers` class, so my usage would be something like:

```
if(someOtherVariable == thisCustomer.priceLevel) //do some stuff

someString = thisCustomer.priceLevel.ToString()
```

-

```
public enum priceLevels
{
    SELECT = 2,
    PLUS = 3,
    PREMIER = 3,
    EFI = 4,
    MSELECT = 5,
    SPECIAL = 6
}

class PriceLevel
{
    public priceLevels priceLevel { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string myString = "No Level Set";

        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.SELECT) return "Partner-Select";
        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.PLUS) return "Plus/Premier";
        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.PREMIER) return "Plus/Premier";
        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.EFI) return "eFi Plus-SPA";
        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.MSELECT) return "mSelect";
        if (priceLevel == priceLevels.SPECIAL) return "Special";

        return myString;
    }
}
```

Would anyone be able to suggest an alternate object that I can use in place of the `priceLevels` enum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you use `priceLevels` for something else. because if you change `PriceLevel` class or remove the `priceLevels` enum, meybe you need to change `Customer` class too or the way how to save the price level value.

If you keep `priceLevels` enum. You can use a attibute description for this and include in your project a simple extension:

```
public enum priceLevels
{
    [Description("Partner-Select")]
    SELECT = 2,
    [Description("...")]
    PLUS = 3,
    [Description("...")]
    PREMIER = 3,
    [Description("...")]
    EFI = 4,
    [Description("...")]
    MSELECT = 5,
    [Description("...")]
    SPECIAL = 6
}

public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var fi = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString());

    var attributes = (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);

    return (attributes != null && attributes.Length > 0)
                ? attributes[0].Description
                : enumValue.ToString();
}
```

Use:

```
someString = thisCustomer.priceLevel.priceLevel.GetDescription()
```

or you can change your `Customer` class and include in this a property `PriceLevel` with the type `priceLevels`:

```
 someString = thisCustomer.PriceLevel.GetDescription()
```

When I use this, somethimes I include a resource file. because I can save muy description in this resouce.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I need the `PriceLevel` anywhere else, so I think it makes the most sense to add the property to my class. As far as me needing to be able to change the index of the enum, I think I will just use that to correspond to an array with default values, then I can just have a settings file, and if it has some other values for the enum it will change the value in the array.

Answer (score 1):

If the main reason not to use `Enum` is the `ToString()`, you can override the result by adding an attribute on the members and using an extension method as @andres suggested; if you want a more complex structure, you can simulate an enum and add functionalities:

```
public struct PriceLevels
{
    public static PriceLevels NONE = 0;

    public static PriceLevels SELECT = 2;
    public static PriceLevels PLUS = 3;
    public static PriceLevels PREMIER = 3;
    public static PriceLevels EFI = 4;
    public static PriceLevels MSELECT = 5;
    public static PriceLevels SPECIAL = 6;

    public bool Equals(PriceLevels other) => _number == other._number;

    public override bool Equals(object obj) => !ReferenceEquals(null, obj) && obj is PriceLevels && Equals((PriceLevels) obj);

    public override int GetHashCode() => _number;

    readonly int _number;

    PriceLevels(int number)
    {
        _number = number;
    }

    public static implicit operator PriceLevels(int number) => new PriceLevels(number);

    public static bool operator ==(PriceLevels leftLevel, PriceLevels rightLevel) => leftLevel._number == rightLevel._number;

    public static bool operator !=(PriceLevels leftLevel, PriceLevels rightLevel) => !(leftLevel == rightLevel);

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (this == SELECT) return "Partner-Select";
        if (this == PLUS) return "Plus/Premier";
        if (this == PREMIER) return "Plus/Premier";
        if (this == EFI) return "eFi Plus-SPA";
        if (this == MSELECT) return "mSelect";
        if (this == SPECIAL) return "Special";

        return "No Level Set";
    }
}
```